# ElasticBeanstalk Ruby PostDeploy Script Mission Impossible

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

We have recently updated our ruby/elasticbeanstalk platform to AWS Linux 2 / Ruby (Ruby 2.7 running on 64bit Amazon Linux 2/3.2.0)

A part of our Ruby deployment is a delayed_job (daemon gem)

After many attempts to have a bash script from the .platform/hooks/postdeploy/ folder, I have offically declared I am stuck. Here is the error from eb-engine.log:

````
2020/12/08 04:18:44.162454 [INFO] Running platform hook: .platform/hooks/postdeploy/restart_delayed_job.sh
2020/12/08 04:18:44.191301 [ERROR] An error occurred during execution of command [app-deploy] - [RunAppDeployPostDeployHooks]. Stop running the command. Error: Command .platform/hooks/postdeploy/restart_delayed_job.sh failed with error exit status 127

2020/12/08 04:18:44.191327 [INFO] Executing cleanup logic
2020/12/08 04:18:44.191448 [INFO] CommandService Response: {"status":"FAILURE","api_version":"1.0","results":[{"status":"FAILURE","msg":"Engine execution has encountered an error.","returncode":1,"events":[{"msg":"Instance deployment failed. For details, see 'eb-engine.log'.","timestamp":1607401124,"severity":"ERROR"}]}]}```
````

Here is one of many scripts I have attempted:

````
#!/bin/bash
#Using similar syntax as the appdeploy pre hooks that is managed by AWS
exec 3>&1 4>&2
trap 'exec 2>&4 1>&3' 0 1 2 3
exec 1>delayed_job_err.out 2>&1

# Loading environment data
# source /etc/profile.d/sh.local #created from other .ebextension file
EB_APP_USER=$(/opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config platformconfig -k AppUser)
EB_APP_CURRENT_DIR=$(/opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config platformconfig -k AppDeployDir)
#EB_APP_PIDS_DIR=/home/webapp/pids

/opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config environment | jq -r 'to_entries | .[] | "export \(.key)=\"\(.value)\""' > /tmp/envvars
source /tmp/envvars
cd /var/app
cd $EB_APP_CURRENT_DIR
su -s /bin/bash -c "bin/delayed_job restart" $EB_APP_USER```
````

Here is the delayed_job file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require File.expand_path(File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), '..', 'config', 'environment'))
require 'delayed/command'
Delayed::Command.new(ARGV).daemonize
```

As you can see I'm doing my best to load up the env variables. The delayed_job seems to run just fine as root from within the EB Linux 2 host with the env vars loaded.

```
total 12
-rwxrwxr-x 1 webapp webapp  179 Dec  8 04:15 001_load_envs.sh
-rw-r--r-- 1 root   root    251 Dec  8 04:46 delayed_job_err.out
-rwxrwxr-x 1 webapp webapp 1144 Dec  8 04:15 restart_delayed_job.sh
[root@ip-172-16-100-178 postdeploy]# cat delayed_job_err.out
/var/app/current/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/json-1.8.6/lib/json/common.rb:155: warning: Using the last argument as keyword parameters is deprecated
delayed_job: warning: no instances running. Starting...
delayed_job: process with pid 5292 started.
```

Any help would be appreciated..

Comment: Does the log file `eb-engine.log` have anything useful in it?

Comment: You will laugh when I tell you that snippet was from eb-engine.log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am also using elasticbeanstalk on Amazon Linux 2

I am using resque which needs a restart postdeploy. Following is my postdeploy hook which restarts resque workers
`.platform/hooks/postdeploy/0020_restart_resque_workers.sh`

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
. /opt/elasticbeanstalk/deployment/env
cd /var/app/current/
su -c "RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake resque:restart_workers" webapp ||
echo "resque workers restarted."
true
```

Notice the environment variable setup. It simply executes `/opt/elasticbeanstalk/deployment/env` which will give you the environment.

Hope you are able to use above script by simply replcaing command to restart delayed job instead of resque workers.

Comment: also with new platform on elastic beanstalk they have a default upgrade option enabled under 'Elasticbeanstalk > environments > YOUR_ENV > Conifiguration > Modify Managed Updates` if this is enabled elastibeanstalk will automatically update your ec2 instance platforms to new upgraded Amazon LInux 2 os. make sure this upgrade won't create a problem for your application

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the timeout to post your script and answer. I really appreciate you making an effort to help me. It worked like a charm. I wish you a lot of luck and success in your future.